# How to find files in a folder that name starts with a specific String in Android

Tags: java, android

Can someone help me...

I am making an Android app and i need now to search for files in *Download* folder of my device and if i find files that name starts with `data` then call a function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
File dir = Environment
    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.getName().startsWith("data")) {
        // it's a match, call your function
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Since the `protectionLevel` of this permission is `dangerous`, on API level 23+ you need to request this permission at runtime. Check out the corresponding [developer's guide article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following changes to your code :-

1) Add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your manifest.xml file

2)  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); 
Then you can use File.list() or File.listFiles() to get all the file in the directory into array .

You can loop on the returned array and you can use regular expression to search the file :-

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^data");
```

Then write the matcher statement :-

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());               
 if(!matcher.find()) {
            // do your method call here                     
 }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ArrayList< File > getFileList( File downloadFolder, String preFixFilter )
   {
       ArrayList< File > filteredFileList = new ArrayList< File >();
       for( File file : downloadFolder.listFiles() )
       {
            if( file.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith( preFixFilter.toLowerCase() ) )
            {
                 filteredFileList.add( file );
            }
       }
       return filteredFileList;
   }
```